# MakeXYEventLayer_management not creating final file?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, coordinates

I'm using python to generate x and y coordinates for the start and end of lines in Arc. I have successfully done this part but when I try and generate the nodes I have no idea where the output file ends up or if it even exists. I get no errors when running the script but I just don't get an output points layer at all. I've tried defining the workspace and also tried not including this line. When I run the Make XY Event Layer from the toolbox it works fine. Can somebody help me with where I'm going wrong!?

[image]

Comment: You are not showing the full code, what is RtNET?

Comment: Also, Make XY Event layer doesn't create a shapefile. You have to export your event layer for that to happen.

Comment: It's an open layer selected by the user:

# Routed SCRIM network
RtNET = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Comment: Martin: how do I export my event layer?

Comment: How are you running this script, from within ArcMap or in an IDE? As Martin eluded to an Event layer is a virtual layer which needs to be saved to create an actual dataset. Use the Select tool in the analysis toolbox to save it.

Comment: Not sure in Python, but try arcpy.Copy_management or arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion

Comment: I'm running the script from the toolbox, the aim is to generate X and Y coordinates for line start and end (done) then create points from these coordinates. Thanks Martin, I'll give it a go

Comment: arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion worked, thank you!

Comment: @Martin Please consider including your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make XY Event layer doesn't create a shapefile, it's only a virtual layer. You have to export your event layer for that to happen.

Try using arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion().